# R: Compute a rolling sum on irregular time series grouped by id variables with time-based window

Tags: r, time-series, grouped-table

I love R but some problems are just plain hard.

The challenge is to find the first instance of a rolling sum that is less than 30 in an irregular time series having a time-based window greater than or equal to 6 hours. I have a sample of the series

```
Row Person  DateTime    Value
1   A   2014-01-01 08:15:00 5
2   A   2014-01-01 09:15:00 5
3   A   2014-01-01 10:00:00 5
4   A   2014-01-01 11:15:00 5
5   A   2014-01-01 14:15:00 5
6   B   2014-01-01 08:15:00 25
7   B   2014-01-01 10:15:00 25
8   B   2014-01-01 19:15:00 2
9   C   2014-01-01 08:00:00 20
10  C   2014-01-01 09:00:00 5
11  C   2014-01-01 13:45:00 1
12  D   2014-01-01 07:00:00 1
13  D   2014-01-01 08:15:00 13
14  D   2014-01-01 14:15:00 15

For Person A, Rows 1 & 5 create a minimum 6 hour interval with a running sum of 25 (which is less than 30).
For Person B, Rows 7 & 8 create a 9 hour interval with a running sum of 27 (again less than 30).
For Person C, using Rows 9 & 10, there is no minimum 6 hour interval (it is only 5.75 hours) although the running sum is 26 and is less than 30.
For Person D, using Rows 12 & 14, the interval is 7.25 hours but the running sum is 30 and is not less than 30.
```

Given n observations, there are n*(n-1)/2 intervals that must be compared. For example, with n=2 there is just 1 interval to evaluate. For n=3 there are 3 intervals. And so on.

I assume that this is an variation of the subset sum problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

While the data can be sorted I suspect this requires a brute force solution testing each interval.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit: here's the data with DateTime column formatted as POSIXct:

```
df <- structure(list(Person = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
DateTime = structure(c(1388560500, 1388564100, 1388566800, 
1388571300, 1388582100, 1388560500, 1388567700, 1388600100, 
1388559600, 1388563200, 1388580300, 1388556000, 1388560500, 
1388582100), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
Value = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 25L, 25L, 2L, 20L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 13L, 15L)), .Names = c("Person", "DateTime", "Value"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found this to be a difficult problem in R as well.  So I made a package for it!

```
library("devtools")
install_github("boRingTrees","mgahan")
require(boRingTrees)
```

Of course, you will have to figure out your units correctly for the upper bound.

Here is some more documentation if you are interested.
https://github.com/mgahan/boRingTrees

For the data `df` that @beginneR provided, you could use the following code to get a 6 hour rolling sum.

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[ , roll := rollingByCalcs(df,dates="DateTime",target="Value",
                    by="Person",stat=sum,lower=0,upper=6*60*60)]

    Person            DateTime Value roll
 1:      A 2014-01-01 01:15:00     5    5
 2:      A 2014-01-01 02:15:00     5   10
 3:      A 2014-01-01 03:00:00     5   15
 4:      A 2014-01-01 04:15:00     5   20
 5:      A 2014-01-01 07:15:00     5   25
 6:      B 2014-01-01 01:15:00    25   25
 7:      B 2014-01-01 03:15:00    25   50
 8:      B 2014-01-01 12:15:00     2    2
 9:      C 2014-01-01 01:00:00    20   20
10:      C 2014-01-01 02:00:00     5   25
11:      C 2014-01-01 06:45:00     1   26
12:      D 2014-01-01 00:00:00     1    1
13:      D 2014-01-01 01:15:00    13   14
14:      D 2014-01-01 07:15:00    15   28
```

The original post is pretty unclear to me, so this might not be exactly what he wanted.  If a column with the desired output was presented, I imagine I could be of more help.

Comment: +1, Nice! Can you demonstrate how the output of your function using the OP's sample data would look?

Comment: Sure thing!  @Dave M, could you please use `dput` on your data?  Or could you make your data reproducible somehow?

Comment: I had alread created the data, so I added a dput to the question

Comment: Remarkable. And very much appreciated. I am not at work at the moment but spent the weekend dreaming of a solution - to no avail. The sequences are not that long in the actual data set but there are likely 30,000 persons to process. So I'll keep you posted. And many thanks.

Comment: Sure thing!  And if you need a speed-up (and you are running Mac OSX or Linux), then you can change the cores from 1 to as many as you want.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that an interval is defined by two rows for the same person.  For each person, We want the first such interval (time-wise) of at least 6 hours for which the sum of `Value` of those two rows and any intermediate rows is less than 30.  If there is more than one such first interval for a person pick one arbitrarily.

This can be represented by a triple join in SQL.  The inner select picks out all rows consisting of the start of interval (`a.DateTime`), the end of interval (`b.DateTime`) and rows between them (`c.DateTime`) grouping by `Person` and interval and summing over the `Value` provided it spans at least 6 `hours`.  The outer select then keeps only those rows whose `total` is < 30 and for each `Person` keeps only the one whose `DateTime` is least.  If there is more than one first row (time-wise) for a `Person` it picks one arbitrarily.

```
   library(sqldf)

   sqldf(
     "select Person, min(Datetime) DateTime, hours, total 
      from (select a.Person, 
          a.DateTime, 
          (b.Datetime - a.DateTime)/3600 hours, 
          sum(c.Value) total
          from DF a join DF b join DF c
          on a.Person = b.Person and a.Person = c.Person and hours >= 6
          and c.DateTime between a.DateTime and b.DateTime
          group by a.Person, a.DateTime, b.DateTime)
      where total < 30
      group by Person"
   )
```

giving:

```
  Person            DateTime hours total
1      A 2014-01-01 08:15:00  6.00    25
2      B 2014-01-01 10:15:00  9.00    27
3      D 2014-01-01 07:00:00  7.25    29
```

**Note:** We used this data:

```
DF <- data.frame( Row = 1:14,
  Person = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
             4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"),
  DateTime = structure(c(1388582100, 1388585700, 1388588400, 1388592900, 
             1388603700, 1388582100, 1388589300, 1388621700, 1388581200, 
             1388584800, 1388601900, 1388577600, 1388582100, 1388603700), 
             class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
  Value = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 25L, 25L, 2L, 20L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 15L) )
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.9.8 (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016), the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package has gained the ability to *aggregate in a non-equi join*.

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- setDT(df)[, CJ(start = DateTime, end = DateTime)[
  , hours := difftime(end, start, units = "hours")][hours >= 6], by = Person]
df[tmp, on = .(Person, DateTime >= start, DateTime <= end), 
  .(hours, total = sum(Value)), by = .EACHI][
    total < 30, .SD[1L], by = Person]
```

> ```
>    Person            DateTime      hours total
> 1:      A 2014-01-01 08:15:00 6.00 hours    25
> 2:      B 2014-01-01 10:15:00 9.00 hours    27
> 3:      D 2014-01-01 07:00:00 7.25 hours    29
> ```

`tmp` contains all possible intervals of 6 and more hours for each person. It is created through a cross join `CJ()` and subsequent filtering:

```
tmp
```

> ```
>    Person               start                 end       hours
> 1:      A 2014-01-01 08:15:00 2014-01-01 14:15:00  6.00 hours
> 2:      B 2014-01-01 08:15:00 2014-01-01 19:15:00 11.00 hours
> 3:      B 2014-01-01 10:15:00 2014-01-01 19:15:00  9.00 hours
> 4:      D 2014-01-01 07:00:00 2014-01-01 14:15:00  7.25 hours
> 5:      D 2014-01-01 08:15:00 2014-01-01 14:15:00  6.00 hours
> ```

These intervals are being used to aggregate over in the non-equi join. The result is filtered for a total value of less than 30 and the first occurrence for each person is picked, finally.